# Swift: Error handling with throwing escaped closure (confusing)

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to make a nice way to handle errors using a UIAlertController with an option to retry the code causing the error. I came up with this huge mess that somehow actually works:

```
func handleError(_ closure: @escaping () throws -> Void) {
  do {
    try closure()
  } catch {
    print(error)
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let retry = UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: {(_: UIAlertAction) in self.handleError(closure)})
    alert.addAction(retry)
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)
    alert.addAction(cancel)
    present(alert, animated: true)
  }
}
```

However, just looking at this, it seems like it would cause more errors than prevent them. Is there anything I could do to make this simple or less confusing? I can't understand why I need the @escaping part (but the compiler tells me I do), or why I need to provide a blank argument for the UIAlertAction closure.

I just need some reassurance that this isn't too bad of a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of @escaping is let you aware that your closure will be executed in a asynchronous call. Think in this way: suppose you must call a function that you didn't developed yourself and must pass a closure to it. Now suppose that you are expecting that the closure will be executed as a synchronous call. How could you know if it will be used only as a synchronous call? Swift use the @escaping annotation to give you this assurance. If the function is used in any asynchronous call you must inform this in the function signature. In your case, you're passing the function to an AlertController that will be waiting for user action to call the closure.

And about the blank argument, actually this is not a blank argument, it is a function signature. Here you are telling the compiler that you will receive a function as a argument, and this function has no arguments and returns nothing, but can throw an exception. In swift, functions have types. A function that receive a string as a argument and returns a Boolean is of the type `(String)-> Bool`. With the empty parameter, you are defining the type of the function that you will accept as a argument, in this case your function type is `() -> ()`, with can be summarized as `()` and means: a function that has no argument and returns nothing.

You can find more information about function types in swift [here](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2016/03/18/swift-functions-as-types/).

By the way, I think your code is right. I don't see any problems, but to give you a proper response I must know what will be in your closure.

Comment: The closure can be any code that needs 'try' in front of it to work. I want to use it all over the place for all kinds of things

Comment: There are no relations with the try and closures. You must use try before calling any function that could throw exceptions. If a operation can throw a exception (think a controlled error) you must use try. A closure is a special type of function that you can pass as a argument to other functions.

Comment: Is there any part of this code that I could simplify? I'm mainly thinking about the (_: UIAlertAction) part

Comment: I don't think so. It is a little confusing because it was made very simple. You can make things more clear, but you'll need to make it more verbose. Maybe other person can have a different opinion.